# BigQuery - 1 file duplicate out of many using Java API

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using Java API quick start program to upload CSV files into bigquery tables. I uploaded more than thousand file but in one of the table 1 file's rows are duplicated in bigquery. I went through the logs but found only 1 entry of its upload. Also went through many similar questions where @jordan mentioned that the bug is fixed. Can there be any reason of this behavior? I am yet to try a solution mentioned of  setting a job id. But just could not get any reason from my side of the duplicate entries...

Answer (score 0):

Since BigQuery is append only by design, you need to accept there will be some duplicates in your system, and be able to write your queries in such way that selects the most recent version of it.

Comment: I actually went back to the CSV files that I have uploaded and used grep to find all the duplicate entries they are in a single file. Is there any chance that the file was uploaded but received failure due to which it was uploaded again?

Comment: Can you provide a job id of the job where the file was added multiple times?

Comment: I have tried bq tool to check jobs, bq ls -j command it listed jobs  in which there wasn't any load job on 2014/12/09 on which I had uploaded the file and got duplicates. All jobs on that day while also on many other days just shows type as query and not load. This makes it difficult for me to track the load operations.

Comment: Are you running streaming inserts? as those don't show up in job list.

Comment: What error codes and numbers you see in this link (you need to replace project id) https://console.developers.google.com/project/{project_ID}/apiui/apiview/bigquery?tabId=usage

Comment: To insert I am using code given in documentation page(sample code). The working is it opens the CSV file all its contents is appended into a string and insert function is used on the job created. I tried for the suggested link its just showing {{apiCtrl.api.name}}